# How can I sort an array of enums with associated values in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, enums

First question on StackOverflow… Please be kind. :)

I have an array of enums with associated values which I would like to sort chronological. One of these values contains a date (as a String) which gets displayed and should be used for sorting.

Here is what it looks like at the moment:

```
enum cellType {
    case standard(text: String, icon: UIImage, hasChildren: Bool, reference: String)
    case detailed(text: String, secondaryText: String, icon: UIImage, hasChildren: Bool, reference: String)

    var identifier: String {
        switch self {
        case .standard: return "standardCell"
        case .detailed: return "detailedCell"
        }
    }
}

var cellData: [cellType]
```

Then the `cellData` gets populated with some `cellType`s. The value for `secondaryText` contains the date and it looks like this:

```
print(cellData) 

// [
//    AppIdentifier.cellType.detailed(text: "Title A", secondaryText: "2017-10-20T10:04:00.000+02:00", icon: <UIImage: 0x60c0002a6660>, {12, 21}, hasChildren: false, reference: "40693"),
//    AppIdentifier.cellType.detailed(text: "Title B", secondaryText: "2016-12-14T10:04:00.000+02:00", icon: <UIImage: 0x60c0002a6660>, {12, 21}, hasChildren: false, reference: "40632")
//    AppIdentifier.cellType.detailed(text: "Title C", secondaryText: "2017-10-20T10:07:00.000+02:00", icon: <UIImage: 0x60c0002a6660>, {12, 21}, hasChildren: false, reference: "40694"),
//    AppIdentifier.cellType.detailed(text: "Title D", secondaryText: "2017-11-16T10:34:00.000+02:00", icon: <UIImage: 0x60c0002a6660>, {12, 21}, hasChildren: false, reference: "40633"),
//    AppIdentifier.cellType.detailed(text: "Title E", secondaryText: "2017-10-19T10:12:00.000+02:00", icon: <UIImage: 0x60c0002a6660>, {12, 21}, hasChildren: false, reference: "40682"),
// ]
```

When I tried to sort the array, the following was apparently too simple:

```
var cellDataSorted = cellData.sorted(by: {$0.detailed.secondaryText < $1.detailed.secondaryText})

// Swift Compiler Error: enum element ’detailed’ cannot be referenced as an instance member
```

What would be the best way to sort this array? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I’d suggest searching for how to sort and array of enums in Swift. I am sure that this question has been answered before. If not there are definitely questions that will help you answer the question yourself.

Comment: @sasquatch I read that page. Please tell me what you didn’t like so I can fix it and do better next time. Thanks.

Comment: @Fogmeister I did search and I read several posts on sorting enums in an array. Neither did I find something specific for the associated values nor could I figure it out by myself by reconstructing other approaches. Maybe I'm too new in this swift-thing… However, I wouldn't have asked when other posts gave me a hint in the right direction. Feeling quite stupid now… :-/

Comment: Ok, when I get back to my laptop I’ll be able to add an answer. But it’s very similar to other answers here. I think. Anyway, the first step is to conform to the “Comparable” protocol. Once that is done your sort is trivial :-)

Comment: @Marc: Come up with what you tried and tell what exactly didn't work. Asking for `best way to sort` seems generic.

Comment: @sasquatch I tried to address what I did and mentioned the resulting error in the last code block. And I get that _best way to sort_ is not the best wording… Next time, I'll do better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

(I am writing this on the phone, so.. fix the syntax if necessary)

Use following code within the sorted function:

```
if case .detailed(_, let date0, _, _, _) = $0, case .detailed(_, let date1, _, _, _) = $1 {
     return date0 < date1
} else {
    // One of them didn't have date (should never happen)
    return true
}
```

Your problem is, that you are accessing the parameters of the enum as if it was an instance of a class/struct.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. It works as intended and the array gets properly sorted. However `date0` and `date1` need to be defined as a constant: `let date0` and `let date1`. Maybe you could edit your answer accordingly?